# Unable to remove an HTML element from an object not in the DOM

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't the following remove the `div` with class `hidden`?

```
var data = 'This is a message <div class="hidden"> <ul id="canceledOrders"> <li>502301</li> </ul> </div>';
$(data).find(".hidden").remove();
```

After running the above, `data`'s value remains the same. Is the `div` not removed because `data` is not in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You removed the element from the DOM tree created by `$()`.
That doesn't affect the string it was parsed from.

You need to get the HTML source of the newly modified DOM tree:

```
var data = ...;
var tree = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");

tree.find('.hidden')
    .remove();

data = tree.html();
```

See [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html) for a more detailed explanation.